# DELETE HTTP VERB: Does not work in production mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have this code:

> index.html.erb

```
<table id="coinsTable" class="table table-hover table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th ><%= @coins.human_attribute_name(:url_image) %></th>
      <th><%= @coins.human_attribute_name(:acronym) %></th>
      <th><%= @coins.human_attribute_name(:descripition) %></th>
      <th><%= @coins.human_attribute_name(:mining_type) %></th> 
      <th><%= t('quotation_BRL') %></th>
      <th><%= t('quotation_USD') %></th>
      <th colspan="6"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @coins.each do |coin| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= image_tag coin.url_image, size: "40x40" %></td> 
        <td id="coin_acronym"><%= coin.acronym %></td>
        <td><%= coin.descripition %></td>
        <td><%= coin.mining_type.description %></td>
        <td id="<%= coin.acronym %>">Indisponível</td>
        <td id="<%= "#{coin.acronym}_USD" %>">Indisponível</td>
        <td><%= link_to t('links.show'), coin %></td>
        <td><%= link_to t('links.edit'), edit_coin_path(coin) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to t('links.delete'), coin, method: :delete, data: { confirm: t('links.are_sure') } %></td> // DELETE VERB

      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The `link_to` helper with the `DELETE VERB METHOD` does not work in production mode, it redirects to my controller action `#show`.

In development mode it works normally. I tried to delete and precompile assets several times and the same "error" occurs.

My controller `Coin` code:

> coins_controller.rb

```
class CoinsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :set_coin, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :set_MiningTypes_Options, only: [:new, :edit, :create, :update]

  # GET /coins
  # GET /coins.json
  def index
    @coins = Coin.all
  end

  # GET /coins/1
  # GET /coins/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /coins/new
  def new
    @coin = Coin.new
  end

  # GET /coins/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /coins
  # POST /coins.json
def create
  if @coin = Coin.new(coin_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @coin.save
        format.html { redirect_to @coin, notice: 'Moeda criada com sucesso.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @coin }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @coin.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
end

  # PATCH/PUT /coins/1
  # PATCH/PUT /coins/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @coin.update(coin_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @coin, notice: 'Moeda atualizada com sucesso.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @coin }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @coin.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /coins/1
  # DELETE /coins/1.json
  def destroy
    @coin.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      # CRIA O FORMATO DA RESPOSTA PARA RETORNO PADRAO EM HTML
      format.html { redirect_to coins_url, notice: 'Moeda apagada com sucesso.' }
      # CRIA O FORMATO DA RESPOSTA PARA RETORNO EM JSON
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # RECEBE O :ID RECEBIDO E SETA @COIN
    def set_coin
      @coin = Coin.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Only allow a list of trusted parameters through.
    def coin_params     
        params.require(:coin).permit(:descripition, :acronym, :url_image, :mining_type_id) # FILTRA OS PARAMS E BUSCA APENAS OS LISTADOS
    end

    def set_MiningTypes_Options
      @mining_types_options = MiningType.all.pluck(:description,:id)
    end

end
```

Comment: Please post your controller code.

Comment: @dbugger, post updated, thanks!

Comment: You also might want to do a security check in your `set_coin` method. E.g. `current_user.coins.find_by(id: params[:id])` is much safer.

Comment: This error is almost certainly due to a javascript error. Rails relies on Rails UJS to add an event handler to links with the `data-method` attribute. If you have not included Rails UJS on the page or have any script errors that are preventing it from working the browser will just send a GET request because thats what links do in the the browser. You really need to start by opening the web console in the browser and checking for errors and ensuring that Rails UJS is included on the page (hint check for the global Rails). https://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html

Comment: You can also use `<%= button_to t('links.delete'), coin, method: :delete, data: { confirm: t('links.are_sure') } %>` which creates a form just containing a single button and does not rely on javascript.